# Can you hear the difference between "immeasurable" and "measurable"?

Tags: listening

[sound track](https://soundcloud.com/xi-zhang-819295156/man-is-immeasurable-man-is-immeasurable)

There are several "man is immeasurable" and "man is measurable" in this sound track. But I can only hear out "man is measurable".

I want to know it is an ear problem or it is a listening problem.

Comment: i can definitely hear the difference: 1,2 - immesurable, 3,4 - mesurable, 5,6,7 - immesurable, 8,9,10 - mesurable, etc

Comment: That speaker is nearly swallowing the first syllable, **im**,  That recording is *not* representative of how most native speakers (of AmE) would pronounce the word, at least not speakers who would use the word **immeasurable** in their normal conversation.

Comment: That is like a torture session. This question is really off topic as posed. Also, fyi, that sentence is highly questionable. Wealth may be measurable and immeasurable but "man" (in the sense of humanity) surely is not.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it seems this is a computer-generated voice.  You should not use these to improve your listening skills, as computer voices tend to mispronounce words, especially in context.  Instead rely on recordings of native speakers.